# Output to a file, using input from another file

Tags: perl, input, output

I'm trying to output to a file, using input from another file. No keyboard input.

I know I'm on the right track, my syntax is just a little off.

Basically, I'm taking records from the file "boot.log", using pattern matching selecting certain records and outputting them to a file named "bootlog.out". I haven't gotten to the pattern matching part yet. Here's what I have...

```
open (BOOTLOG, "boot.log") || die "Can't open file named boot.log: $!";

while ($_ = <BOOTLOG>)
{
print $_;
}

open (LOGOUT, ">bootlog.out") || die "Can't create file named bootlog.out: $!\n";

close (LOGOUT) || die "Can't close file named bootlog.out: $!\n";

close (BOOTLOG) || die "Can't close the file named boot.log: $!";
```

How do I print the contents of boot.log to bootlog.out?

EDIT1

This seems to take the input and output it to the second file. Is the syntax correct?

```
open (BOOTLOG, "boot.log") || die "Can't open file named boot.log: $!";

open (LOGOUT, ">bootlog.txt") || die "Can't create file named bootlog.out: $!\n";

while ($_ = <BOOTLOG>)
{
print $_;
print LOGOUT $_;
}

close (LOGOUT) || die "Can't close file named bootlog.txt: $!\n";

close (BOOTLOG) || die "Can't close the file named boot.log: $!";
```

Comment: Always: `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use output file handle `LOGOUT` along with `print`. Also you need to open output file handle before actually printing to it.

```
open (BOOTLOG, "boot.log") || die "Can't open file named boot.log: $!";
open (LOGOUT, ">bootlog.out") || die "Can't create file named bootlog.out: $!\n";
while (<BOOTLOG>)
{
    print LOGOUT $_;
}  
close (LOGOUT);
close (BOOTLOG);
```

---

**Note :** It is recommended not to use bareword file handles. I would prefer rewriting above piece of code as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;    

open my $fh_boot_log, '<', 'boot.log' or die "Can't open file 'boot.log': $!";
open my $fh_log_out, '>', 'bootlog.out' or die "Can't create file 'bootlog.out': $!\n";
while (<$fh_boot_log>)
{
    print $fh_log_out $_;
}  
close $fh_log_out;
close $fh_boot_log;
```

Comment: I'm just beginning, I'm trying to keep my code as simple as possible. Thanks for the help, but the advice you gave doesn't create an output file with records.

Comment: @LMN0321 Are you getting any error? Otherwise it should work.

Comment: No I'm not getting an error, it just wasn't creating an output file. I added an extra line and that seemed to work, tho I'm not sure if its the correct syntax, or if its actually writing to the file.

Comment: Code pasted in comment won't be readable. Update it in your question. I have no reason why my above code won't work.

Comment: @LMN0321 that edit seems fine. It will print input file content to output file as well as termial. I don't get your issue.

Comment: How can I use a counter to add up all the records? Do I use a foreach loop? I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: yes, loop should work. I don't understand why you say you're not sure where to put! just put it and give it a try, see what's happening. Consider going through perl tutorials. many are available online.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using magic `<diamond operator>` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print;
}
```

Usage in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
$ perl script.pl < input.txt > output.txt
```